# Set value in select2 option by data from database

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I want to make edit from. In this form contain input form control using select2 option. This select2 option input form can't display selected data that return from the database. I want to make the select2 option can be change  too. I've tried this but still can display the selected data. Thank You :)

Here's my view

```
  <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php echo form_open('company2/do_update') ?>
  <form>
  <select id="Name" class="searching form-control" style="width:500px" name="company"></select>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light">Save</button>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
  </form>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.searching').select2({
        placeholder: 'Masukkan Nama Company',
        ajax:{
            url: "<?php echo base_url('company2/select2'); ?>",
            dataType: "json",
            delay: 250,
            processResults: function (param) {
    return {
      compClue: param.term,

    };
  },
  processResults: function(data){
                var results = [];

                $.each(data, function(index, item){

                    results.push({
                        id: item.Name,
                        text: item.Name,
                        value:item.Name
                    });
                });
                return{
                    results: results,
                    cache: true,
                };
            }
        }
    });
    var response = {};
        response.val = "<?php echo $row['Name'];?>";
        $("#searching option[value='" + response.val +"']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: first store `var myselect = $('.searching').select2();` this in some variable then at the end after setting the selected attribute just trigger change event of select2 `myselect.trigger("change");`

Comment: your processing and fetching the options will remain as it is.

Comment: and you should set selected after the response render completed otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would just output the content you want for the select to a div using PHP and then get the div content and append somewhere using javascript if needed.

```
<div id="selectOptions">
    <?php
        foreach($option as $row){
            $optionVal = $row->optionVal;
            $optionLabel = $row->optionLabel;
            echo "<option value='$optionVal'>$optionLabel</option>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Since you are already using jQuery you can then get the content of the div using:

```
var options = $('#selectOptions').html();
```